# Utilizador novato

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, novos-usuários

Este utilizador [user7752](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7752/user7752), já tem 4 perguntas, quase todas com a mesma forma, se bem percebi as 4 perguntas são quase as mesmas, ou seja, 4 duplicadas. Não sei é por causa de ser novo cá, que anda com dificuldades em fazer perguntas.

A pergunta que tenho para fazer é:

O que fazer nesta situação?

Comment: Bom, em termos do que fazer com as perguntas, já está feito, estão todas fechadas (precisaria olhar novamente com mais cuidado, pra ver se uma delas pelo menos poderia ficar aberta). Já em relação ao usuário, parece estar precisando de orientação, seja de um usuário comum, via comentários, ou do próprio Gabe via mensagem privada, se ele achar necessário.

Comment: @bfavaretto Então seria aconselhável sinalizar a(s) pergunta(s)?

Comment: Como você já trouxe o caso pro meta, nem é necessário, o Gabe vai ver.

Comment: @bfavaretto o duro é saber quando :)

Comment: @Gabe alguma resposta?